# c# regex find 2 isolated char in password

Tags: c#, regex, char, passwords, quantifiers

i didn't find another solution for this specific problem, so i hope you guys can help.

I need to test if a given password has 2 or more uppercase letters and i want to use regular expressions to do so. what i have now is this:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(passw, @"([A-Z]){2,}")){
            Note += 1;
        }
```

only regular expression:

```
@"([A-Z]){2,}"
```

but with this code the programm only works if there are 2 ore more uppercase letters next to each other.

this works:
aAAa

this doesn't:
aAaA

but i need the latter as password can be fully random.

i searched around the web about regular expressions, but {2,} seem to be the best quantifier for the job, or am i completly wrong there?

thanks for any tipps :)

Comment: You need to know count upper case in password or what?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job

```
@"[A-Z].*[A-Z]"
```

Here you search for an uppercase letter (`[A-Z]`), then any string (`.*`), and then another uppercase letter (`[A-Z]`). If you want to be able to increase the number of required uppercase letters easily you can use this:

```
@"([A-Z].*){2,}"
```

Now you look for an uppercase letter, then any string. And you search for this twice or more.

Comment: Thank you very much :) that was exactly the solution i needed.

Comment: So accept it, please!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to find count upper case and digit in password:

```
return password.Length >= z
    && new Regex("[A-Z]").Matches(password).Count >= x
    && new Regex("[0-9]").Matches(password).Count >= y
    ;
```

i hope to help you.